# Wrap tag in Libxml

Tags: php, libxml2

I am currently build on top of an existing libxml code and couldn't find a detailed documentation.

Is it possible to wrap a tag around a node?

I thought this would work:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'pre' );

foreach( $tags as $tag ):

    $handler = $doc->createElement( 'div' );
    $handler->setAttribute( 'class', 'pre_wrapper' );
    $newnode = $handler->appendChild( $tag );

    $tag->replaceNode( $newnode );

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$handler->appendChild($tag)` unlinks the element `$tag` from its original location, so the following `replaceNode` doesn't have the desired effect. This means that you have to swap the order of calls. Also, I couldn't find a `replaceNode` method, but there's `replaceChild` which has to be invoked on the parent node:

```
# Create wrapper element
$handler = $doc->createElement('div');
$handler->setAttribute('class', 'pre_wrapper');
# Replace wrapped element with wrapper
$tag->parentNode->replaceChild($handler, $tag);
# Move wrapped element into wrapper
$handler->appendChild($tag);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsMgEETP4Ss4WAJLsfIBpq7aOrcmvuTQW7WFjbFEDAISq6r67S7EbqXeWM3Mm8FpN8/i0WlHCmUlfaAjTrTtDq2V1wuOkZc1KUL0SRFCsH3XMiKSsyEb4Tw23Yhilx/rfZrseovd3ZYS9Z1dNcaCeju88sxL2LP1CFJTvqg9xr3B3BmeP0/QH@GCnCUUKykEWkToS/pFNoWGURnMi5agTJiIa5YzNdxYov/5qiZgfIrRDx/XmIjSQAhsSzP6ffLgHPolkBqqxoFPmKNVWDUenQGJL3owiv/ytsuUfw0ZMqrVt6jfBKW268QAN8w/L@t5/gE)

Comment: nice one :) thank you. I fiddled around quite a while but couldn't figure it out :/